# Calling a overriden method in subclass from superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I need to make a Activity in Android which will work as a BaseActivity.

I just have a question which i have a some doubts about. Will this work? Is this a good pattern?

```
class SuperClass {

    public void A() {
        ...
        B();
    }

    public void B(){
        //Does this get fired from the SubClass's method A()?
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    @Override
    public void A(){
        super.A();
    }

    @Override
    public void B(){
        ...
        //Or does this?
    }
}
```

My question is when i call `super.A()` in the `Subclass`, will the method `B()` get fired from the `SubClass` or the `SuperClass`?

Comment: A simple **sysout** would clear things for you.

Comment: Yes i know, but one of the reasons i wanted this is to ask a question to the community is when other people are in doubt, they can find the answer, as i couldn't find the answer when i was searching in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` of `SubClass` will be executed (assuming `A` is executed on an instance of `SubClass`). That's exactly how method overriding works. BTW, there's no need to override `A` in the `SubClass` if all it does is call the `SuperClass` method.

Answer (score 0):

"will the method B() get fired from the SubClass or the SuperClass?" - I don't fully understand your question.

Basically A() in the SubClass will call A() in the super class. The superclass will invoke B() of the SubClass.

Comment: It would help you understand things by using some System.out.println in the functions.